# Why are there few separate closed loops in my TSP Little-algorythm solver implementation?

Tags: c#, algorithm, winforms, matrix

I'm trying to implement TSP-solver using branch and bound method and Little's algorythm. The software itself should be used for demonstration purposes in lecturing discrete mathematics.

With the Little's algorythm I'm finding a candidate tour which is then supposed to be compared with other candidate tours. But before even getting to branch and bound I'm expiriencing a problem with results of my Little's algorythm implementation.

I use double.positiveinfinity for removing routes that I already checked and backroute and routes from point x to point x.

Algorythm itself goes as follows:

1. Get a distance matrix of all possible routes
2. Find minimum element for every row
3. For all rows subtract minimum element of corresponding row from every element in that row except infinite ones
4. Find minimum element for every column
5. For all cols subtract minimum element of corresponding col from every element in that col except infinite ones

We will get at least 1 zero in every row and col.

6. For every zero element in matrix calculate a value as a sum of minimum element of corresponding row and minimum element of corresponding col (excluding this zero element itself)
7. Find zero element with highest calculated value. This is a route we will include in our tour
8. Delete from the matrix row and column with this zero element. Also delete from accounting "back route element" (e.g. we found route 3>4, that means we wont go 4>3 anymore in this tour and so we deleting element (4,3)). This is done by assigning double.positiveinfinity to elements of that row and that column and the back route element
9. If we didn't get a full tour, we go to step 2 for our new matrix

Below are functions I wrote.

```cs
//find minimum element in row i of matrix m excluding element with number exc
        private double GetRowMin(double[,] m, int i, int exc = -1)
        {
            double[] SubRow = new double[m.GetLength(1)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(m, 8 * m.GetLength(1) * i, SubRow, 0, 8 * m.GetLength(1));
            if (exc != -1)
                SubRow[exc] = Double.PositiveInfinity;
            return SubRow.Min();
        }

//find minimum element in col j of matrix m excluding element with number exc
        private double GetColMin(double[,] m, int j, int exc = -1)
        {
            double[] SubCol = new double[m.GetLength(0)];
            SubCol = Enumerable.Range(0, m.GetLength(0)).Select(xr => m[xr, j]).ToArray();
            if (exc != -1)
                SubCol[exc] = Double.PositiveInfinity;
            return SubCol.Min();
        }

//reduce matrix m by subtracting minimum for every row and col
        private double[,] MReduce(double[,] m)
        {
            double[,] resm = new double[m.GetLength(0), m.GetLength(1)];
            for (int i = 0; i < m.GetLength(0); i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < m.GetLength(1); j++)
                    if (m[i, j] < Double.PositiveInfinity)
                        resm[i, j] = m[i, j] - GetRowMin(m, i, i);
                    else
                        resm[i, j] = Double.PositiveInfinity;
            for (int i = 0; i < m.GetLength(0); i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < m.GetLength(1); j++)
                    if (m[i, j] < Double.PositiveInfinity)
                        resm[i, j] = m[i, j] - GetColMin(m, j, j);
                    else
                        resm[i, j] = Double.PositiveInfinity;
            return resm;
        }

//find zero element with maximum value
        private Point FindMaxVElem(double[,] m)
        {
            double MaxV = Double.MinValue;
            Point MaxP = new Point();
            for (int i = 0; i < m.GetLength(0); i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < m.GetLength(1); j++)
                    if (m[i, j] == 0)
                    {
                        double s = 0;
                        if (!Double.IsInfinity(GetRowMin(m, i, j)))
                            s += GetRowMin(m, i, j);
                        if (!Double.IsInfinity(GetColMin(m, j, i)))
                            s += GetColMin(m, j, i);
                        if (Double.IsInfinity(s))
                            s = 0;
                        if (s > MaxV)
                        {
                            MaxV = s;
                            MaxP.X = i;
                            MaxP.Y = j;
                        }
                    }
            return MaxP;
        }

//delete row/col and backroute from accounting
        private double[,] RCSubtract(double[,] m, int l, int n)
        {
            double[,] resm = new double[m.GetLength(0), m.GetLength(1)];
            for (int i = 0; i < m.GetLength(0); i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < m.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    if (i == l || j == n)
                        resm[i, j] = Double.PositiveInfinity;
                    else
                        resm[i, j] = m[i, j];
                }
            resm[n, l] = Double.PositiveInfinity;
            return resm;
        }
```

Driver code is something like this:

```cs
public List<PointD> PList; //list for storing coordinates of all points
        double[,] AdjM; //distance matrix
        List<Point> path; //here will be unordered subroutes of the tour

...

for (int i = 0; i < PList.Count; i++)
            {
                AdjM = MReduce(AdjM);
                path.Add(FindMaxVElem(AdjM));
                AdjM = RCSubtract(AdjM, path.Last().X, path.Last().Y);
            }
```

In most cases (both simple and complex) everything is fine and the tour is found. The problem is, instead of getting a full closed tour of all points my Little's algorythm implementation on a **few separate groups of tightly localized points** returns a **few separate closed tours** like this:

(guess I don't have enough reputation to post an image, sorry) https://pp.userapi.com/c849236/v849236895/174a46/ASAPt1F8zs4.jpg

Step by step matrix are solving like this:

```
    0     1     2     3     4     5     Min
--------------------------------------------
 0: нет   25,4  31,5  146,3 159,6 140,2 25,4 
 1: 25,4  нет   24,8  160,3 176,3 159,3 24,8 
 2: 31,5  24,8  нет   138,3 155,9 141,2 24,8 
 3: 146,3 160,3 138,3 нет   26,3  40,8  26,3 
 4: 159,6 176,3 155,9 26,3  нет   27,9  26,3 
 5: 140,2 159,3 141,2 40,8  27,9  нет   27,9 
Min 25,4  24,8  24,8  26,3  26,3  27,9  310,9

    0     1     2     3     4     5     Min
--------------------------------------------
 0: нет   0,5   6,7   120,1 нет   112,4 0,5  
 1: 0     нет   0     134,1 нет   131,5 0    
 2: 6,2   0     нет   112   нет   113,3 0    
 3: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 4: 134,2 151,5 131   нет   нет   0     0    
 5: 114,9 134,5 116,3 14,6  нет   нет   14,6 
Min 0     0     0     14,6  нет   0     29,7 

    0     1     2     3     4     5     Min
--------------------------------------------
 0: нет   0,5   6,7   105,5 нет   нет   0,5  
 1: 0     нет   0     119,5 нет   нет   0    
 2: 6,2   0     нет   97,4  нет   нет   0    
 3: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 4: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 5: 114,9 134,5 116,3 0     нет   нет   0    
Min 0     0     0     0     нет   нет   0,5  

    0     1     2     3     4     5     Min
--------------------------------------------
 0: нет   0,5   6,7   нет   нет   нет   0,5  
 1: 0     нет   0     нет   нет   нет   0    
 2: 6,2   0     нет   нет   нет   нет   0    
 3: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 4: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 5: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
Min 0     0     0     нет   нет   нет   0,5  

    0     1     2     3     4     5     Min
--------------------------------------------
 0: нет   0,5   нет   нет   нет   нет   0,5  
 1: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 2: 6,2   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   6,2  
 3: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 4: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 5: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
Min 6,2   0,5   нет   нет   нет   нет   13,4 

    0     1     2     3     4     5     Min
--------------------------------------------
 0: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 1: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 2: 0     нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   0    
 3: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 4: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
 5: нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   нет  
Min 0     нет   нет   нет   нет   нет   0
```

So i know I did something wrong (probably messed up handling the infinity), since already first iteration on separately localized groups of points returns a few closed tours instead of one. But I can't figure out what exactly is going wrong. Anyone have any ideas?